# Using the_tags() function to display two tags as list elements

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying the format `the_tags` WordPress function to display the tag text in an `li`. But encountering issues as no `li` is being rendered:

I've tried to format `the_tags()` like so:

```
<?php the_tags( $before, $sep, $after ); ?>
```

Where (from the codex):

> **$before** (string) Text to display before the actual tags are displayed.
>
> **$sep** (string) Text or character to display between each tag link.
>
> **$after** (string) Text to display after the last tag.

Here is my current approach:

```
$tags = the_tags();

if ($tags) {
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $count++;
        the_tags('','<li></li>', '');
        // echo '
        //  <li class="postLabel__tags">
        //      <a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a>
        //  </li>';
        if( $count >= 2 ) break; // only show 2 tags
    }
}
```

With the above, it prints out `Tags: tag1, tag2`. I don't want the "Tags:" text to be there and neither the comma. Unsure why `the_tags('','<li></li>', '');` does not resolve this?

And the rendered HTML markup of the above is the following:

```
<a href="#" rel="tag">tag1</a>
", "
<a href="#" rel="tag">tag2</a>
```

Whereas I want it to be:

```
<li class="postLabel__tags"> 
    <a href="#" rel="tag">tag1</a>
</li>

<li class="postLabel__tags"> 
    <a href="#" rel="tag">tag2</a>
</li>
```

Comment: try `var_dump(the_tags());` I guess the_tags return is not an array so you can not use it in a for loop

Answer (score 1):

`the_tags()` **echoes** list of tags. And returns nothing, so `$tags` variable is empty.

Your code should be reduced to:

```
the_tags(
    '<li class="postLabel__tags">',
    '</li><li class="postLabel__tags">', 
    '</li>'
);
```

To get tags as a list and control outputting them manually use [`get_the_tags();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/).